# Why did these 8 lines of code cause a laptop to shut off and BIOS beep instead of booting up?

Tags: ruby, cmd, hardware

I was toying around with an expendable laptop, writing loops for simple entertainment, as I'm a sound technician at my High School and there was a break in rehearsals. I ended up with these 8 lines:

```
type = "1234567890abcdef"
while 1 == 1
     type = type.split("").shuffle.join("")
     system("color " + type[0] + type[1])
     system("start main.rb")
     r = rand(2)
     print r
end
```

I ran it in the cmd and after about 25 minutes it turned off, but the HDD and CPU usage lights by the mousepad stayed on. The only way to make it do anything was to remove the battery. Upon trying to start it up again, it flashed 5 times (It is a 2010 or so Toshiba laptop, I don't know what model, so we couldn't look up the BIOS codes). We managed to fix it with a CMOS reset and then reseating the HDD. When it finally started up, it automatically ran Windows Boot Repair. Why does it do this?

**Edit: It has 2GB of RAM, an Intel Pentium 2.4GhZ Dual-core CPU, and Intel Integrated Graphocs. Windows 7.

***Another note, I WAS intendant on doing something like this to it. I was trying for this result, but I am confused as to how it worked.

Comment: Infinite loop duplicating itself -> overload on system ressources -> overheating -> safety shutdown -> abnormal termination of windows -> boot repair procedure at restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you called this program `main.rb`. If that's the  case, then it's an infinite loop that calls itself, well, infinitely and in a different process (in fact, a different console window) each time. That'll eventually deplete system resources, but it doesn't explain the weird shut-off behavior.

Comment: I was thinking it would overload the RAM for sure, but I didn't think it would behave so strangely. I did.

Answer (score 2):

I can see a fork bomb overheating a laptop in 25 minutes.  Is the fan broken?

Comment: No overheat. I had the laptop in my hands in the tech booth, walking around, checking LAV packs. The fan is working, and there appears to be no heat damage.

Comment: There may appear to be no heat damage, but what does your dmesg say?  I am almost sure your hand is not going to be objective about a core temperature.   CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal                          
CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (
total events = 24)

Answer (score 1):

This code wouldn't cause any damage. It was probably just a coincidental failure.

Comment: We checked; it did it twice. It opened thousands of Command Console's that flashed a random colour and printed out a one or a zero.

Comment: I agree with the coincidence. Try running a program to stress-test your memory like [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) or other components and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: We did reproduce the issue; CPU usage was at 100%, and the RAM hovered at 1.8GB until the shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
while 1 == 1
```

creates an infinite loop, causing the program to run forever.  No idea why it did anything but hang though.